# Android: how to make a bitmap border transparent?

Tags: android, bitmap, transparent

I have a bitmap and I just want to show central circle area. How to hide the corner area? Actually, it would be great if I could make any area transparent (e.g. make it a ring)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the bitmap to a transparent PNG - you can use the free Gimp application. Load your picture in Gimp, select the central circle area, copy, then paste as new image. Should automatically make the area around it transparent. Then just save as a PNG file and use that in your Android app.

**UPDATE**

Here's an answer I found for defining a color to be transparent: [Android bitmap mask color, remove color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432965/android-bitmap-mask-color-remove-color)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works and I'm accepting it. However, it would be nice if someone could tell me how to do using android API.

Comment: Added a link to another method.