# Android Convert a bitmap to Grayscale but keep one Color

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap, grayscale

I want to set my whole bitmap to grayscale, but I want to keep one color, red or blue or green or any color the user likes?
Is this possible with a colormatrix?
Here's a link, that's what I want to do but in android.
[How can I convert an RGB image to grayscale but keep one color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063965/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-to-grayscale-but-keep-one-color)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Good challenge, actually! Look at here and the related doc to achieve that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6488289/2545832

Comment: I tried it,but it just makes my bitmap brighter. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ImageView imageView;
Bitmap photo,photo1;
photo1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(photo.getWidth(),photo.getHeight(),photo.getConfig());

for(int i=0;i<photo.getWidth();i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<photo.getHeight();j++){
        int p=photo.getPixel(i,j);
        int r= Color.red(p);
        int g=Color.green(p);
        int b=Color.blue(p);
        int alpha=Color.alpha(p);
        r=0;
        g=g+150;
        b=0;
        alpha=0;
        photo1.setPixel(i,j, Color.argb(Color.alpha(p),r,g,b));
    }
}
imageView.setImageBitmap(photo1)
```

Comment: You should add some narrative to your answer. Answers with just code will get deleted.